# Question about the function of this それ

Tags: grammar

I read the definition for 偽る:

> 本心や真実を隠して，それと違うことを言う

I found that それと means "and, also", so I interpreted it like: To hide true feelings and the truths and also say wrong/different this. But isnt それと only used in spoken language? - this definition I found in 大辞林. I'm thinking それ here just acts like an "extra", like:

"to say this and that and different/wrong things"

Is this correct, or is the first interpretation correct? Or is the それ pointing to something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not それと. It's それ + と. The clue is in the verb 違う. When you compare things, you compare them **with** something, and that something is marked by と.

So this それ is simply 'that'. And 'that' is the 'truth' that you are hiding. それと違うことを言う = "say something different from that".